# Excel hyperlink works only once each time Excel is restarted

Tags: excel, hyperlink, vba

I need to prevent Excel hyperlinks from being redirected by website scripts.  Details are below.

In a Microsoft Excel spreadsheet, I use the formula `=hyperlink("url")` to define hyperlinks to various websites.  For most websites, the hyperlinks work as expected; however, some websites have implemented a script to redirect the hyperlink after the first click.  The first time I click on the hyperlink after starting Excel, the hyperlink works correctly.  Subsequent clicks on the hyperlink are redirected until I restart Excel.  I am able to defeat the script (and thus prevent the redirect) by adding the website domain to Internet Explorer's "Restricted Sites" (under the IE Security tab); however, this breaks other functionality of the hyperlinked website.  How can I prevent this unwanted redirect without adding the domain to Restricted Sites?  If I could somehow clear the hyperlink cache after the hyperlink is clicked (using Excel VBA), that would be an acceptable option.

I am running Excel 2016 (32-bit) in Windows 7 (32-bit) with IE 11.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same exact problem. My default browser is chrome, but somehow IE was affecting Excel links. I added the website to IE's restricted sites which allowed me to actually open the link. Since chrome is my default browser, it opens up and works perfectly in chrome (retains functionality).